move assignment argument throws error when dereferenced but works when member accessed directly
In the minimum needed code snippet, in the move assignment, why is the commented line *arg = nullptr; illegal and arg.p = nullptr; okay? If I understand correctly, both are modifying rvalue, yet on compilation *arg = nullptr; produces error saying:

left operand must be l-value

I would expect *arg to provide access to arg's p because of operator overloading.
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Ptr {
public:
    Ptr(double arg) :p{ new double(arg) } {}
    // copy constructor
    Ptr(const Ptr& arg) {
        p = new double(*(*arg));
    }
    // move assignment
    Ptr& operator=(Ptr&& arg) {
        delete p;
        p = *arg;
        cout << "move type of *arg " << typeid(*arg).name() << endl;
        arg.p = nullptr;
        //*arg = nullptr; // illegal
        return *this;
    }
    double* operator*() {
        return p;
    }
    const double* operator*() const {
        return p;
    }
    ~Ptr() {
        delete p;
    }
private:
    double* p;
};

Ptr copy(Ptr a) { return a; }


int main() {
    Ptr pt{ 2 };
    Ptr pt2{ 3 };
    pt2 = copy(pt);
    return 0;
}

Tried chatGpt for help, however, it thinks I am trying to assign a pointer to a double which is clearly not the case because if I do cout << "type of *arg " << typeid(*arg).name()<<endl; a pointer type is seen.
EDIT:
Removed misleading comment for operator*. I would like to keep the code as is. Problem is partly from PPP3, Chapter 17, drill by Bjarne Stroustrup. I am interested in the WHY.

*allows to read and write p Nope. You wanted double*& operator*().

"Tried chatGpt for help..." AI is not a good/trusted source for coding problems especially for a language like c++.

Your overloaded operator*'s return by value which means a call to those functions is an rvalue expression.

"Both are modifying rvalue". No, arg.p is a lvalue expression, even arg itself is a lvalue expression, although its declared type is "rvalue reference". This misconception has been addressed on SO for so many times.

"If I understand correctly, both are modifying rvalue," -- The origin of the name "rvalue" is "right side of an assignment value".  You're asking about the left side of an assignment (which gave rise to the name lvalue)...

@JaMiT I interpret it as "both are modifying rvalue, so it cannot be the case that only one of them works".

operator*() returns a copy of the memory address of p which is a hexadecimal integer. To return this by reference, return double*&.

@WeijunZhou "I interpret it as [...]" -- You can interpret it that way if you want. It has no bearing on my point that "modifying the rvalue (through assignment)" should immediately make one suspect that the claimed understanding might be incorrect.

Now I realize the comment for operator* is wrong, however I would still like to keep code as is. The problem is partly from PPP3 chapter 17, drill by Bjarne Stroustrup

@BrunoMraz "I am interested in the WHY..." I've explained the why in my answer below. Currently, *arg is an rvalue expression. If you change the return type to be of lvalue reference, then it will become lvalue expression.


I would expect *arg to provide access to arg's p because of operator overloading.

The problem is that your overloaded operator*'s return by value which means a call to those functions as in *arg is an rvalue expression.
To solve this, you can return the pointer by lvalue reference as shown below.
//---------v------------------>return by reference
    double*& operator*() {
        return p;
    }

Working Demo

I would like to clarify to see if I understand correctly, I can interpret operator* as a function call like this Ptr::operator*(pt) and because pt got extracted its rvalue in move assignment because of Ptr&& arg, operator* continues returning rvalue, which is data, not variable.
On the other hand arg.p is accessing a member, where arg is an rvalue and everything after dot is an lvalue, because that is simply how C++ as a language behaves.
Am I on the right track with this explanation? If yes, then I could say it is just the matter of C++ syntax in this case.

@BrunoMraz It's much simple than that. For example, whenever we have a  function that returns by value say like int func(); then the call to that function like func() is an rvalue. Now say if we have another function like int& bar(); then when a call to this second function like bar() is an lvalue expresison. These are from the definitions of lvalue, rvalue etc. Similarly, for dot operator . , there are different rules for operands and its result. In your example, arg.p is an lvalue expression.

Now I understand, thank you for the explanation. The transition from double* to double*&  in operator* now makes sense to me.

@BrunoMraz You're welcome :)
